# Access ArrayList items in onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver class in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, broadcastreceiver

i developing an application where i want to block SMS of User create List.for this purpose i have one an Activity and Second is BroadcastReceiver class. in Activity class i have a function which return the ArrayList,and in BroadcastReceive class i want to access that arrayList,but my code is not access that ArrayList.what is the issue in my code?
Please guide me..
NumberListActivity.java
this is a list class.

```
public class NumberListActivity extends Activity {
    ListView numList1;
    Button btnAdd1;
    public ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sms_list);
        numList1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Smslist);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
                list.add(edit.getText().toString());
                edit.setText("");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
        numList1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getArrayList(){
        return list;

    }

}
```

SmsLock.java
 in this class i want to Access arrayList..

```
public class SmsLock extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    String phoneNumber;
    String senderNum;
    NumberListActivity ma = new NumberListActivity();
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {
            adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
            Toast.makeText(context, adapter.getCount()+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage
                            .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    if (senderNum.contains(adapter.getItem(i))) {
                        abortBroadcast();
                    }
                }

            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to access the instance variable `list` in `NumberListActivity` from `SmsLock`? Because right now you have two seperate lists in the two classes.

Comment: @DrewGalbraith: yes Sir i want to save list in SmsLock class from NumberListActivity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to access list in SMSLock class is, make **list** object to **static**. You can preferred this if your list is not different from instance to instance.

Comment: Sir what does mean instance to instance.

Comment: Means if need multiple copy of same object than do not use static. static will generate single copy of that object.

Answer (score 0):

Intent in = getIntent();

ArrayList aList = in.getExtras().getIntegerArrayList("key");